# Setting dropdown value after AJAX call not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.NET MVC application, and one of the pages has dropdowns to select Country and State.  This page collects customer data, including the address.

I followed [this](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1145/mvc-dropdownlistfor-fill-on-selection-change-of-another-dropdown) tutorial to set it all up so that the State values are populated when the Country is selected.

So, I have it working fine when a new customer is added that the Country drop down is populated, and when you change the value for Country, the State dropdown is refilled, and on submitting the form, I get the StateID and CountryID in the model.

What I'm having problems with is on editing a customer, when the model already has a StateID and CountryID, I can get the Country dropdown to select the correct value, but not the State dropdown.

The `FillStates()`method below is used to populate the State dropdown when the Country value is changed.

```
function FillStates() {

   var countryID = $("#CountryID").val();

   $.ajax({
       url: '/Customers/GetStates',
       type: "GET",
       dataType: "JSON",
       data: { CountryID: countryID },
       success: function (states) {
           $("#StateID").html("");
           if (Object.keys(states).length > 0) {
               $("#StateID").append($('<option></option>').val(0).html('Select a State'));
           }
           else {
               $("#StateID").append($('<option></option>').val(0).html(''));
           }

           $.each(states, function (i, state) {
               $("#StateID").append(
                   $('<option></option>').val(state.StateID).html(state.Name));
               });
           }
    });
}
```

For editing a customer though, I need to fill the States dropdown on page load AND select the correct value from the dropdown.

Here's the javascript that should do exactly that...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.when(FillStates()).done(function (e) {
        $("#StateID").val('@Model.StateID');                
    });            
});
```

But this isn't working - I've debugged it and (let's assume the model has StateID = 8) when it hits the line `$("#StateID").val('8');` that line executes without error but doesn't change the selected value of the dropdown.

If I were to move that line into the bottom of the `FillStates()` method, it DOES change the selection properly - but that would then execute every time the Country is changed, instead of only executing once when the page loads.

Why is the exact same line of code `$("#StateID").val('8');` working fine when it's inside the `FillStates()` method, but not working when I execute it after `FillStates()` completes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it is not working is the code inside your `[$when`][1](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) is being executed even before you load your options to the SELECT element. If you put a console.log('something') in both the places, you can see it.

`$when` expects a promise to be returned by the method passed into it. Your `FillState` method is not returning a promise. Your code will work if you change your `FillStates` method to return a promise.

```
function FillStates() {
    var countryID = $("#CountryID").val();

    return $.ajax({
        // Other code goes here
    });
}
```

If you do not wish to do that, You can simply pass the state id to the `FillStates` function and set the selected value there.

```
function FillStates(stateId) {

   var countryID = $("#CountryID").val();

   $.ajax({
          url: '/Post/GetStates',
          type: "GET",
          dataType: "JSON",
          data: { CountrId: countryID },
          success: function (states) {
             $("#StateID").html("");
             if (Object.keys(states).length > 0) {
                $("#StateID").append($('<option></option>').val(0).html('Select a State'));
             }
             else {
                    $("#StateID").append($('<option></option>').val(0).html(''));
             }

           $.each(states, function (i, state) {
            $("#StateID").append($('<option></option>').val(state.Value).html(state.Text));
           });
          if (stateId != null) {
               $("#StateID").val(stateId);
          }
        }
    });
 }
```

Then call it with and without the `stateId` value as needed

```
FillStates(@Model.StateId); // call it for your edit on page load
FillStates();   // call it When user changes country
```

You do not need `$when` in this case.

Comment: Thanks, this is the first time I've used $when, and I thought it just would wait until the AJAX call was done, then run whatever code I put in the .done function.  I guess that's not how it works though.  Passing the StateID into the FillStates method is a good solution though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the `jqXHR` object, returned from `$.ajax()`, from `FillStates()`, or the `$("#StateID").val()` will be executed before your select is filled with data.

```
function FillStates() {
  var countryID = $("#CountryID").val();
  return $.ajax({ ... });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is a good answer +1.  The accepted one though gave a little more detail and a suggestion for a better way to go about it.